# CSS split page: left side expansion causes float to move down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="left" style="float:left; width=20%"></div>
<div id="right" style="float:right"/>
```

I am loading 2 pages using jquery to above div's. when the page in left is expanded due to its content, the right side div is getting down/moving.
any way to keep the right side not changed?

Answer (score 1):

You need this: https://jsfiddle.net/56ocrp17/

```
#left {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}

#right {
  width:80%;
  float:left;
}
```

You need to specify a width for the right side element. It works when both have `float:left;` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
clear:both;
```

You can find more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: clear:both causes the right pane to go down instead of floating in right